# How to generate a SOAP request using php?

Tags: php, soap

I am not getting how to generate a SOAP request using php.

Comment: Do you know PHP, and know what SOAP is?

Comment: I don't know anything about SOAP

Comment: Well, there is your problem. Google it and start reading. Come back when you at least know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All You have to know is here:

- http://php.net
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php.

You have simple PHP & SOAP example [HERE](http://www.vankouteren.eu/blog/2009/03/simple-php-soap-example/).